# Adding Extra Routes to route table using terraform module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am adding routes to route table using module. Below is my code. It runs successfully but routes don't get added.

module.tf: (This checks if the publicRoute & privateRoute has more than one item, it will add that many routes to route table)

```
resource "aws_route" "public_routes" {
  count   = length(var.ExtraRoutes.publicRoute) > 1 ? length(var.ExtraRoutes.publicRoute) : 0
  route_table_id            = aws_route_table.VPCPublicSubnetRouteTable[0].id
  destination_cidr_block    = length(regexall("^[0-9].*.[0-9].*",var.ExtraRoutes.publicRoute[count.index].destination)) != 0 ? var.ExtraRoutes.publicRoute[count.index].destination : null
  gateway_id = length(regexall("^igw-.*",var.ExtraRoutes.publicRoute[count.index].target)) != 0 ? var.ExtraRoutes.publicRoute[count.index].target : null
}
resource "aws_route" "private_routes" {
  count   = length(var.ExtraRoutes.privateRoute) > 1 ? length(var.ExtraRoutes.privateRoute) : 0
  route_table_id            = aws_route_table.VPCPrivateSubnetRouteTable[0].id  
  destination_cidr_block    = length(regexall("^[0-9].*.[0-9].*",var.ExtraRoutes.privateRoute[count.index].destination)) != 0 ? var.ExtraRoutes.privateRoute[count.index].destination : null  
  gateway_id = length(regexall("^igw-.*",var.ExtraRoutes.privateRoute[count.index].target)) != 0 ? var.ExtraRoutes.privateRoute[count.index].target : null
}
```

module_var.tf (I am keeping it only a map)

```
variable "ExtraRoutes" {
  type = map
  default = {
    publicRoute  = []
  privateRoute = []
  }
}
```

main.tf (As I need the first item in ExtraRoutes for something else I want from count.index + 1)

```
module "ExtraVPCs" {
  source = "./modules/VPC"
  count  =  length(var.ExtraRoutes)
  ExtraRoutes = {
    publicRoute = var.ExtraRoutes[count.index + 1].publicRoute
    privateRoute = var.ExtraRoutes[count.index + 1].privateRoute
  }  
}
```

main_var.tf

```
variable "ExtraRoutes" {
  type = list(object({
    publicRoute            = list(object({
        destination = string
        target = string
  })
  )
  privateRoute = list(object({
    destination = string
        target = string
  }))
  }))
}
```

init.tfvars (There are 2 items in ExtraRoutes. It should add the 2nd item in Route table but it's not working as expected.

```
ExtraRoutes = [
  {
  publicRoute = [
      {
        destination = "10.0.0.0/32"
        target =  "igw-092aba6c187183f48"
      }
      ]
  privateRoute = [
      {
        destination = "10.0.0.0/32"
        target =  "igw-092aba6c187183f48"
      }
      ]
},
 {
  publicRoute = [
      {
        destination = "10.0.0.0/32"
        target =  "igw-0acf4f7ac1e7eba47"
      }
      ]
  privateRoute = [
      {
        destination = "10.0.0.0/32"
        target =  "igw-0acf4f7ac1e7eba47"
      }
      ]
}
]
```

Comment: "not working as expected" is not specific. Exactly what is actually happening, and what exactly should be the expected outcome.

Comment: It should add the route to the route table. Instead, the job is successful but nothing is getting added which makes me think may be it's not getting any value but there is no error. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check the length of a list using `>0`, not `>1`:

```
 count   = length(var.ExtraRoutes.publicRoute) > 0 ? length(var.ExtraRoutes.publicRoute) : 0
```

TF counts items from `0`. When you use `>1`, in your case you end up with `count = 0`.

Comment: I think it has something to do with module_var.tf. This gives Error: destination: string required.

Comment: @MayaRay This is `var.ExtraRoutes.publicRoute[count.index].target` is incorrect and not due to "string required". I don't think what you posted in SO actually represents your code. The error, or rather lack of them, is strange.

Comment: I meant the behavior of the code in general has something to do with module_var.tf. I think the way I have defined the variable ExtraRoutes in module and child is not correct.
The error I mentioned is what I am getting after I used your solution.

Comment: I don't think this will work either because the input data isn't easy to parse like they're trying to. If you look at `var.ExtraRoutes` it's a list so you can't access it like `var.ExtraRoutes.publicRoute`. I think this needs a much more extensive rework to be doable and would probably need that input data structure to change if possible.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Thanks. I also though the same, but `var.ExtraRoutes` is a map. There are two variables called `ExtraRoutes`. One in main (list) and one in the module (map). The question is very confusing.

Comment: @Marcin It worked. Thanks :) Yes the code developed is very confusing but it worked with your solution.